# Rails and query: matches where ALL associations.attribute == true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a rails 3 project:

I have matches that has_many competitions. Every match will have 2 competitions and competitions are pending(true/false).

I need all matches where ALL its competitions are not pending.

I can get matches where one competition is false:

```
scope :confirmed, joins(:competitions).where("pending = ?", false)
```

But that's just not quite good enough.

Please let me know if I need to show more code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If its feasible from the object domain, you could create two differently names 1:1 associations.

Answer (score 0):

If its feasible from the object domain, you could create two differently names 1:1 associations.

If not, you could use a sql query to find the match_ids:

```
Match.find_by_sql(%q{SELECT * FROM "matches" WHERE id IN (SELECT "match_id" FROM "competitions"  WHERE ("pending" = 'f') GROUP BY "match_id" HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)})
```

But this also depends on having at most 2 competitions for each match.